# Is it possible to chain an event handler programatically in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to figure out a way to trigger the validation routines on an input element when a button is clicked in the same form.  I've been looking at a few different ways of doing this.  What seems to be the least convoluted is to create a directive that modifies an input button to fire the $validate method on the target form element.  I've set this up without too much trouble but I've gotten blocked at how to modify the ngClick event handler so that it triggers the $validate while leaving the original HTML-defined ngClick intact.

I was attempting to use the directive template function to extract the original ngClick method and chain it to the new ngClick function defined in the directive.  This started to turn into a mess quite quickly and I'm concerned about how brittle it might be.

Is there a way to intercept the ngClick handler in a directive and to still have the original functionality intact?

Alternately, I'm open to suggestions about how to fire the validation routines on the input field when the button is clicked with minimal involvement of the controller layer.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger the validation routines"? Typically validation just runs, and you can react to it by showing messages with `ng-show="form.$invalid"` and the like... or, are you trying to prevent any kind of validation done (this may make sense in async validation). Also, try to clarify your question. It starts with validation routines, but actually talks about intercepting ng-click handlers

Comment: I need to manually trigger the validation routines as there are sometimes changes in the data that will not get picked up by the input control validation.  Namely, other controls can trigger changes to scope values that are not bound to the input control.  One of the input control validations is a cross-check between scope variables for duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical example of an [XY-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) (if not a double-XY-question).

You don't need to "chain event handlers" (whatever you mean by that). Neither do you need to, I think, trigger the validation manually just because you are validating against external data.

Validation in Angular just runs - and it is not meant to be triggered other than by changing the data.

To add your own custom validator you need to create a directive (which it seems like you did). In that directive you probably need to specify what you are validating against, like an array of strings against which you want to check for duplicates.

Let's say, for simplicity, that you want to validate against another value in the ViewModel. Suppose, this how it would be used:

```
<input ng-model="bar">
<form name="form1">
  <input ng-model="foo" not-equal-to="bar">
</form>
<span ng-show="form1.$error.notEqualTo">error: foo is equal to bar</span>
```

So, you need to create a directive `notEqualTo` that adds a validator to the `ngModel.$validators` pipeline. This directive also needs to `$watch` for changes to `bar` and re-set the validity:

```
app.directive("notEqualTo", function(){
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    scope: {
      notEqualTo: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){

      // register "notEqualTo" validator
      ngModel.$validators.notEqualTo = function(modelValue){
        return validate(modelValue, scope.notEqualTo);
      };

      // rerun validation on changes to scope.notEqualTo
      scope.$watch("notEqualTo", function(){
        ngModel.$setValidity("notEqualTo", 
                                validate(ngModel.$modelValue, scope.notEqualTo));
      });

      function validate(one, other){
        return one !== other;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/05tiWfWjPuNp04CMu9CY?p=preview)

Comment: I'm already doing something similar to what you're describing and it works.  My reason for wanting to move the validation refresh trigger to the button onClick is that there may be many fields that are going to have to watch multiple scope variables - some of which will require changes to multiple watched variables on change.  I'm concerned about the performance impact of all the watches on the input fields.  I was hoping to be able to remove many of the input watches and simply have them manually run validation on the submit click.  Sounds like that solution is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: @DanHeidel, you could always add a dependency on `$rootScope` to the directive function, and add a single `$watch` there for all directives of the same type.